# Selecting edges for a random geometric graph in an arbitrarily shaped domain

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

I have some code to generate a random geometric graph in a domain of specificed shape (here an H-shape). Edges cannot exist when they intersect the domain boundary (so we need line of sight for edges to exist).

Here is the domain shape:

```
    reg[a_, b_, w_] := 
 RegionUnion[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {a, b}], 
  Rectangle[{a, (b - 1)/2}, {a + w, (b + 1)/2}], 
  Rectangle[{a + w, 0}, {a + w + a, b}]](*Define H-shaped region*)

    regcomp[a_, b_, w_] := 
 RegionUnion[Rectangle[{a, 0}, {a + w, (b - 1)/2}], 
  Rectangle[{a, (b + 1)/2}, {a + w, 
    b}]](*Definte its complement*)

    Region@reg[1, 2, 4]
    Region@regcomp[1, 2, 4]
```

> [image]

This code uses `RegionIntersection` to check each edge, and remove it accordingly.

```
n = 100;
range = 1;
reg[a_, b_, w_] := 
 RegionUnion[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {a, b}], 
  Rectangle[{a, (b - 1)/2}, {a + w, (b + 1)/2}], 
  Rectangle[{a + w, 0}, {a + w + a, b}]](*Define H-shaped region*)

regcomp[a_, b_, w_] := 
 RegionUnion[Rectangle[{a, 0}, {a + w, (b - 1)/2}], 
  Rectangle[{a, (b + 1)/2}, {a + w, 
    b}]](*Definte its complement*)
edgesold = 
 Function[{subsets, b}, 
  Pick[subsets, 
   UnitStep[
    RandomReal[{0, 1}, Length@subsets] - 
     Exp[-b Dot[(subsets[[All, 1]] - subsets[[All, 2]])^2, {1., 
         1.}]]], 0]];(*Make edges for the graph*)
edges[v_] := 
 Module[{e1}, e1 = edgesold[Subsets[v, {2}], 1/range^2]; 
  e2 = Select[e1, 
    RegionDimension@
       RegionIntersection[Line[#], 
        regcomp[1, 4, 2]] > -\[Infinity] &]; 
  DeleteCases[e1, Alternatives @@ e2]
  ] (*Remove edges which intersect boundary*)

gr6[vert_] := 
 Graph[vert, UndirectedEdge @@@ edgesold[Subsets[vert, {2}], beta], 
  VertexCoordinates -> vert];(*Make random geometric graph*)
v = 
 RandomReal[{0, 4}, {n, 2}];
v = Select[v, 
  RegionMember[reg[1, 4, 2], #] == 
    True &];(*Selcted only nodes in H-shaped region*)
graph6 = 
 gr6[v];
rg1 = Graph[v, UndirectedEdge @@@ edges[v], 
  VertexCoordinates -> 
   v](*Build graph on nodes, using only edge not intersecting the \
boundary*)
```

> [image]

Is my arrangement of the commands leading to the long time this takes to run? Or, for example, is it better to call `RegionIntersection` without `Select`? What's the best way to do this in Mathematica? I need to run this on at least n = 10,000 nodes, which seems to take days to run at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

You can speed up by adding more manual checks like convexity and internal intersection code.  Here's the example.

```
regList[a_, b_, w_] := {Rectangle[{0, 0}, {a, b}], 
  Rectangle[{0, (b - 1)/2}, {2 a + w, (b + 1)/2}], 
  Rectangle[{a + w, 0}, {a + w + a, b}]} (* for convexity check *)

hGraph[n_, range_ ,{a_,b_,w_}] :=
    Block[{br, v, epos, pick, memQ, edges, edge1, edge2, member, bounds},
        br = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg[a,b,w], MaxCellMeasure->Infinity];
        v = Select[RandomReal[MinMax[RegionBounds[br]],{n,2}], RegionMember[br,#]==True&];
        epos = Subsets[Range@Length[v], {2}];
        epos = Pick[epos, UnitStep[RandomReal[{0,1}, Length@epos]-Exp[-(1 / range^2) Dot[(v[[epos[[All,1]]]]-v[[epos[[All,2]]]])^2,{1.,1.}]]],0];
        memQ = RegionMember[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[#]] & /@ regList[1, 4, 2];
        member = Transpose[Through[memQ[v]]];
        pick = AnyTrue[Transpose[member[[#]]], And@@#&]& /@ epos;
        edges = v[[#]] & /@ epos;
        edge1 = Pick[edges, pick];
        edge2 = Pick[edges, pick, False];
        bounds = MeshPrimitives[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[regcomp[a, b, w], MaxCellMeasure->Infinity],1];
        pick = ParallelMap[Region`Mesh`IntersectionFreeSegmentsQ[{bounds, Line[#]},"Ignore"->{"EndPointsTouching","PointTouchesEndPoint","PointOverlap"}]&, edge2];
        edge2 = Pick[edge2, pick];
        Graph[v,UndirectedEdge@@@Join[edge1, edge2],VertexCoordinates->v]
    ]

In[362]:= g = hGraph[200, 1, {1, 4, 2}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> Out[362]= {0.075641, Null}

```
In[364]:= g = hGraph[10000, 1, {1, 4, 2}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> Out[364]= {74.0034, Null}

```
Show[{Region[Style[reg[1, 4, 2], Opacity[.6]]], 
  GraphPlot[hGraph[600, 1, {1, 4, 2}], VertexShapeFunction -> "Point",
    EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line", EdgeStyle -> Thickness[.0002], 
   BaseStyle -> Black]}]
```

[image]

Comment: `hGraph[600, 1, {1, 4, 2}]` seems no output in 13.0.1.

Comment: @cvgmt maybe GraphPlot[hGraph[600, 1, {1, 4, 2}]] ?

Comment: Thank you, convexity checks i.e. checking if endpoints are both in a large convex subdomain is what I was trying. Discretising the boundary is also very useful. Also I used ParallelMap when applying the intersection check, which make a big difference on my quad-core Desktop.